# Check if XElement contains specific child node

Tags: c#, xml

Perhaps I am going about this wrong, but I have an XElement storing an XML object like this

```
<call>
   <attempted/>
   <completed>
        <welcomecall/>
    </completed>
</call>
```

This is stored inside a call class object - `call.callinformation` with data type XElement.

How do I parse the property contents (the xml above) and see if completed contains the child node welcomecall (as not every one will)?

I have tried `call.callinformation.Element("completed").Element("welcomecall"`), and other variations, but no luck.

I am trying to assign it to a boolean, like  `hasWelcomeCall =  (code to determine if completed has this child element)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind whether or not it's within a `completed` element, you could just use:

```
var hasWelcomeCall = call.Descendants("welcomecall").Any();
```

If it can be within any one of a number of `completed` elements, but you want to check that it's in `completed` rather than `attempted`, you could use:

```
var hasWelcomeCall = call.Elements("completed").Elements("welcomecall").Any();
```

If you're using C# 6 and there's only ever one `completed` element you could use:

```
var hasWelcomeCall = call.Element("completed")?.Element("welcomecall") != null;
```

Comment: The last solution worked. I will add I was trying to use the syntax call.Element("completed").Element("welcomecall").Value() != null, which threw me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this via XPath.

```
XElement call = XElement.Load("your xml");
XElement welcomeCall = call.XPathSelectElement("descendant::welcomecall");
bool hasWelcomeCall = welcomeCall != null;
```

More about XPathSelectElement [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).